# What will be the appropriate event be in this code in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing

I have a internal frame but everytime any internal frame gets activated the values in the combo box gets duplicated in the drop down list, how to prevent this??

Actually my issue is when ever other internal frames are activated, the combo box starts duplicating

```
private void formInternalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {   

try
  {
     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
     Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ref","sa","niit@123");
     Statement st1=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery("select opid from patient");
     while(rs1.next())
     {
        opid_combo.addItem(rs1.getString(1));
     }}

     catch(Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println(e);
     }
```

Comment: Try clearing the combobox before adding the strings to it.

Comment: Also, what method contains the above code?

Answer (score 2):

You should clear the combobox values before reloading them...

```
private void formInternalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
    // Remove items first
    opid_combo.removeAllItems()
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ref","sa","niit@123");
        Statement st1=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery("select opid from patient");
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            opid_combo.addItem(rs1.getString(1));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

**Nit Pick**

And while I'm here.  It's probably not a very good idea to reload the items EVERY time the frame is made active.  If you require the combo box to be reloaded at some time, you should probably supply a "refresh" option.

Also, it's not a very good idea to do this within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, as it's going to make your application "pause" every time you switch frames.  Instead, use something like a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to load the values in the background

Answer (score 2):

> my issue is when ever other internal frames are activated, the combo box starts duplicating

Don't load the data in the `internalFrameActivated` event. Instead use the `internalFrameOpened` event and it should only be done the first time.